# Facing issue in sending firebase push notification for react native ios

Tags: react-native

Below is an error which we are getting from firebase api, also we have implemented every solution available from internet, but still getting below error -
{
"multicast_ids": [
7528209830142839690
],
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
{
"error": "InvalidApnsCredential"
}
],
"topic_message_id": null
}
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it could be a million reasons:

- Do your bundle id's match. Remember that it's case sensitive and avoid having hyphens in your bundle id
- Did you try sending a push via the GUI console provided by firebase to send notifications?
- If your production app is not receiving push notification but is receiving notification only when running locally via Xcode, then you have uploaded the development certificate to the firebase console, not the production one
- If you have uploaded both production and development certificates, then remove your old Apns, create a new one and upload it to Firebase
- Also try adding your Apple Team id into Firebase (Firebase console->General->Select your App->Team Id)
- For a PR file (APNs auth) it could be that your Key ID is incorrect. Your filename will be in format AuthKey_{KeyID}.p8. The 10 digit KeyId after the AuthKey_) is what you need to add